# Merging CSV Files with missing columns in Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm a new to `pandas` and `python`, so I hope this will make sense.

I have parsed `multiple` tables from a website to `multiple CSV files`, and unfortunately if the value was not available for the parsed data, it was omitted from the table. Hence, I now have CSV files with varying number of columns.

I've used the `read_csv()` and `to_csv()` in the past and it works like a charm when the data is clean, but I'm stumped here.

I figured there might be a way to "`map`" the read data if I first fed the `pandas DF` with all column headers, then I map each file against the columns in the main file.

*E.g*. Once i used `read_csv()`, then `to_csv()` will look at the main merged file and "`map`" the available fields to the correct columns in the merged file.

This is a short version of the data:

```
File 1:
ID, Price, Name, 
1, $800, Jim
File 2:
ID, Price, Address, Name
2, $500, 1 Main St., Amanda


Desired Output:
ID, Price, Adress, Name
1, $800, , Jim
2, $500, 1 Main St., Amanda
```

This is the code I got so far.

```
mypath='I:\\Filepath\\'

#creating list of files to be read, and merged. 
listFiles = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(mypath):
    listFiles.extend(filenames)
    break

# reading/writing "master headers" to new CSV using a "master header" file     
headers = pd.read_csv('I:\\Filepath\\master_header.csv', index_col=0)

with open('I:\\Filepath\\merge.csv', 'wb') as f:
        headers.to_csv(f)

def mergefile(filenames):


    try:
    # Creating a list of files read. 
    with open('I:\\Filepath\\file_list.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(str(filenames)+'\n')

    os.chdir('I:\\Filepath\\')
    # Reading file to add.
    df = pd.read_csv(filenames, index_col=0)


    # Appending data (w/o header) to the new merged data CSV file. 
    with open('I:\\Filepath\\merge.csv', 'a') as f:


    df.to_csv(f, header=False)


except Exception, e:
    with open('I:\\Filepath\\all_error.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(str(e)+'\n')

for eachfilenames in listFiles:
    mergefile(eachfilenames)
```

This code merges the data, but since the number of columns vary, they are not in the right place...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not panda related, however you may find useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26771999/using-dictwriter-to-write-a-csv-when-the-fields-are-not-known-beforehand

Comment: You should do all your merging within `pandas`, using things like `DataFrame.join`, `DataFrame.append`, etc. Only write the result to a file at the end. This will be much less painful than trying to stitch it together by writing bits and pieces separately to a file. `pandas` has *a lot* of tools for combining data, by doing it this way you're missing out on all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete example that demonstrates how to load the files and merge them using `concat`:

```
In [297]:
import pandas as pd
import io
t="""ID, Price, Name
1, $800, Jim"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep=',\s+')
t1="""ID, Price, Address, Name
2, $500, 1 Main St., Amanda"""
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t1), sep=',\s+')
pd.concat([df,df1], ignore_index=True)

Out[297]:
      Address  ID    Name Price
0         NaN   1     Jim  $800
1  1 Main St.   2  Amanda  $500
```

Note that I pass `ignore_index=True` otherwise you will get duplicate index entries which I assume is not what you want, also I'm assuming that in your original data sample for 'File 1' you don't really have a trailing comma in your header line: `ID, Price, Name,` so I removed it from my code above

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the pandas concat[1] function, which defaults to an outer join (all columns will be present, and missing values will be NaN). For example:

```
import pandas as pd

# you would read each table into its own data frame using read_csv
f1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1], 'Price': [800], 'Name': ['Jim']})
f2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [2], 'Price': [500], 'Address': '1 Main St.', 'Name': ['Amanda']})

pd.concat([f1, f2]) # merged data frame
```

[1] http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html